# Flutter custom widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, custom-widgets

How to create a view like this in Flutter?

[image: Equation view]

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea of doing it.

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  Text("a"), 
  Column(
    Text("m"),
    Container(height: 2.0),
    Text("v2)
  ),
  Container(width: 2.0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks but I want a divider in between m and v2

Comment: Updated the answer. You needed a `Container` in the `Column` with some height.

Comment: This one is taking whole screen. But I want it to be wrap-content like Android

Comment: @AsfaqueAhmed You need to use `mainAxisSize` property on Row or Column depending on your need.